# Which hook is fired when inserting media into a post

Tags: filters, hooks, media

I want to add numbering to each image when I insert them into the post.
For example if I insert 3 images into a post, there will be:

1. Image 1
2. Image 2
3. Image 3

I looked through the WordPress documentation, but I can't find which hook is triggered when inserting images into a post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `add_attachment` action is fired when the `wp_insert_attachment()` function is called to add an item to the media library.  Images are added to posts after going into the media library first.  Even when adding via the post editor, items are added to the library with `wp_insert_attachment()` then to the post.

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', function( $post_ID ) { 
    // Do Stuff
});
```

This will not allow you to number items by post, only by instance in the media library.  Whether that works for your purposes, I cannot answer.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_attachment

Comment: Thank you, this is all I want to know, I will figure out the rest

Comment: Note this hook will only fire one time after the attachment gets uploaded into the media library, it will not get fired in any further attaches into any post, for that use [`wp_media_attach_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_media_attach_action/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to hook into the point when the author of a post inserts an image or other attachment into the Wordpress editor, use `image_send_to_editor()`

For example, if you wanted to wrap the image in a `<div>` or `<figure>` each time, you could do it like this:

```
function wrap_attachments($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
  $src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, $size, false );
  $output = "<div id='post-$id media-$id' class='align$align'>";
  $output .= "<img src='$src[0]' alt='$title' width='$src[1]' height='$src[2]' />";
  $output .= "</div>";
  return $output;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wrap_attachments', 10, 9 );
```

Additional explanation [in this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/insert-images-within-figure-element-from-media-uploader/).

Comment: fyi - alt = metadata `alt`, `post_content` = the description, `post_excerpt` = caption; using `wp_get_attachment_image` will generate the html inc `srcset`. `image_send_to_editor` is not available in Gutenberg (yet)

Answer (score 1):

From 5.5.0, there's a new hook [`wp_media_attach_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_media_attach_action/) will monitor the event that fires after any attachment gets attached or detached more easily:

```php
add_action('wp_media_attach_action', function (string $action, int $attachment_id) {
    if ($action !== 'attach') return;
    // do your stuff
});
```

Due to `at/detach` an attachment is just changing the value of [`post_parent`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_parent/) for its post, this hook still won't get fired after the author inserts the attachment into any post editor, for that you'll need [`image_send_to_editor`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/), but this hook won't work when using gutenberg editor: https://github.com/danielbachhuber/gutenberg-migration-guide/blob/master/filter-image-send-to-editor.md https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8472

Even the `image_send_to_editor` still won't get fired when the author is not inserting attachments into the editor by selecting them from the media library, but just directly copying and pasting images or manually writing raw HTML `<img>` tags, if you must catch these cases, the hook [`post_updated`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/) might be your last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the update!